Set Page Name in Excel export of SSRS based on Column Value < or >
I am exporting a report from SSRS to Excel.  I have grouped the data into two (2) pages in SSRS based on whether the value of a single column is less than zero (0) or not.  I want to name one sheet in Excel "Less than zero" and the other "Between zero and 180".
I am using the following expression in the PageName area of the Properties window for my table:
=IIF(Fields!DAYS_TIL_SOL.value<0,"Less_Than_Zero","Between_Zero_And_180")
That expression names the first sheet correctly, but the second sheet remains the same with "(2)" added.
excel tabs
I tried reversing the expression, =IIF(Fields!DAYS_TIL_SOL.value >=0,"Less_Than_Zero","Between_Zero_And_180"), but that resulted in the same naming phenomenon with "Between_Zero_And_180 (2)" instead.
How do I make the page names unique based on the groups I have set?  Thanks!

Used same expression in the Group PageName.  Selected the group which brought up the properties window for the Tablix Member.
